# ExtJs: How to get parent tab of control

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I am currently working on `ExtJs` and I am stuck at a place where I want to iterate through all components and find the parent tab of each component.

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',
    launch : function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
            width: 300,
            height: 200,
            activeTab: 0,
            items: [
                {
                    title: 'Tab 1',
                    bodyPadding: 10,
                    items : [{
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                itemId: 'fieldsetId',
                items: [{
                            xtype: 'checkbox',
                            fieldLabel: 'Check 1'
                        },{
                            xtype: 'checkbox',
                            fieldLabel: 'Check 2'
                        },{
                            fieldLabel: 'Combo 1',
                            xtype: 'combobox',
                            store: ['value1','value2','value3']
                        }]
                }, 
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Reset',
                }]  
                },
                {
                    title: 'Tab 2',
                    html : 'Another one',
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Test',

                    }]
                }
            ],
            renderTo : Ext.getBody()
        }); 
    }
});
```

In above code, when I iterate through all components and log name of the parent tab whether it is `Tab 1` or `Tab 2`

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are iterating through all the components, just do

```
field.up().up()
```

where field is the component of your tab and above statement will return you the parent tabpanel and so with

```
field.up().up().title
```

will return you "Tab 1"

In the same way for tab 2 components it will be

```
field.up() only.
```

If you have only one loop or something to go through all components then you can put a condition that

if(field.up()) returns you the panel then read it\'s title
 else do field.up().up() and then read the title.

I hope this solves you issue.

Comment: The above sample in Question is just a sample. There could be multiple child fields, like Fieldset can have container and controls reside in that. So only `field.up().up()` will not work in such case

Comment: Try this : field.findParentByType('tabpanel').tabBar.items.items[field.getTabIndex()].title

Answer (score 0):

You can use , field.up('tabPanel') to get the reference of the tabPanel, and then from the reference you can get name,title for the tabPanel